# onMapReady is not called

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, permissions

I followed a tutorial on Youtube and he showed steps to make google map apps. so i followed that tutorial and got an logical error in this code.

```
package com.example.mymap;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {



    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){

        mMap = googleMap;
        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG,"onMapReady : Map is Ready");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        getLocationPermission();
    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG,"initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG,"getLocationPermissoin : getting Location Permssions");
        String[] permissions =
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COARSE_LOCATION )== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            }
            else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
        else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);}
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermssionsResults: called...");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE : {
                if (grantResults.length>0){
                    for (int i = 0; i< grantResults.length;i++ ){
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResults: permissions failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                        mLocationPermissionsGranted  =true;
                        Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResults: permissions Success");
                        //initialize map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my map activity and problem is it is not showing me any toast or log for onMapReady method. it was shown me for once when asked for permissions. but after if i close and re open map toast is not shown by onMapReady method. I think that if onMapReady is not executed then map won't be shown to me. but map is showing to me but not toast. i hope you can understand that at every launch map is shown but toast is only shown once when i was asked for permissions.

help me  with this problem. i can't find exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnMapReady()` is triggered by a call to `getMapAsync()` on your `MapFragment`.

To call `OnMapReady` append the following to your `onCreate()`

```
  MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) 
  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

then  call `getMapAsync()` who calls `OnMapReady()`

```
  mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapDisplay.this);
```

On your code you call `initMap()` that calls `getMapAsync()`   only in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, so only when ask for permissions `OnMapReady()` is triggered

Or call `initMap()` in your `OnCreate()` or on permission granded  should work too

Comment: Yes... I did just the same thing. After Reading your answer I got the situation and i edited code in my way. Thanks to you

Answer (score 1):

I got the situation and handled it. Problem was that If permission are given already then Map was not initializing.. so i called `initMap()` method if permission is already granted.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COARSE_LOCATION )== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;

                initMap();
```

Comment: I am happy that you find the solution , i explained the same think in my answer with details and why onMapReady() in not called. your initMap() method only called when permission are given ..